# xmlhttprequest response is unreadable symbols for values <1000

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a S7-1500 PLC webserver and I want to get data from it and display on html page.

My problem is that I can read the tag value successfully if it is > 1000, otherwise I get strange symbols and chars liks �,w also T,~ etc.

Here is the code:

```
btn1.onclick = function()
{
    getDtata();
};

function getDtata()
{ 
    let xhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
       xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
    xhttp = new ActiveXobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("dov").textContent= this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET","DB.html",false);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

The DB.htm contains the tag I want to read :="myTag":

I don't know why I can't get the value if it is < 1000.

Any help will be appreciated.

I tried different tags but same result.

Comment: It's the 21st century, you can stop doing `xhttp = new ActiveXobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");`. In fact, modern code should use `fetch()`, it's much easier.

Comment: This seems like a problem with the webserver, it's not returning properly encoded text.

Comment: Please see [the documentation for the XMLHttpRequestion API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Your approach is what we used 15+ years ago. And in your DB.html file, make sure you have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` (or whichever character encoding that document has).

Comment: Thank you, It worked when add meta charset. I have another question
When I write:
    xhttp.open("GET","DB.html",false); , I get the data correctly but if I write
    xhttp.open("GET",':="myTag":',false); I get error (this page is in quirks mode despite use DOCTYPE)
':="myTag":' -> this is what is written in DB.html
What is the difference?